# android studio autocomplete search from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to android studio and firebase.
I'm trying to make a food recipe application.
Now, I have an ingredients list in firebase as array form.

I want users to search the ingredients that they don't like from the existing lists.
For this, autocomplete search is necessary.

What I want is;

1. The application to show all ingredients from firebase. How can I do that?
2. For example, if a user doesn't like cucumber and the firebase list has cucumber, carrot, kiwi, and so on, the app should show all the ingredients from firebase but when user type c, app shows cucumber and carrot, when he types cu, it only shows cucumber. He can select cucumber and put this ingredient into the 'dislike list'. How can I do that?

Any comment would help me.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



private EditText search;
private ListView listview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    for (int i = 1; i < 40; i++) {

        final String num = Integer.toString(i);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("ingredients").child(num);


        myRef.child("ingredients").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String name = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    adapter.add(name);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("nein");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            String filterText = s.toString();
            if(filterText.length()>0){

                listview.setFilterText(filterText);
            }else{
                listview.clearTextFilter();
            }
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing in the above mentioned code?

Comment: That code does not get ingredient list from firebase

Comment: for that u need to share the data structure of firebase realtime database(screenshot of firebase database ingredient node values)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an AutoCompleteTextView instead of an EditText for search.
Depending on how many ingredients you should update the adapter when the user type, you should do something like this:

```
//Declare the variables
    private AutoCompleteTextView suggestion_box;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
//this should be in onCreate (for activity) or in onCreateView (for fragment)
suggestion_box = (AutoCompleteTextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.suggestion_box);
```

For firebase you should implement an OnComplete to fill the adapter and update the suggestion box
Check [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming search is an AutoCompleteTextView, you could have just added the adapter to the search like

```
private AutoCompleteTextView search;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

search.setAdapter(adapter);
```

just comment this code

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        String filterText = s.toString();
        if(filterText.length()>0){

            listview.setFilterText(filterText);
        }else{
            listview.clearTextFilter();
        }
    }
});
```

to test mine.